# Internal error Transformation Module PFPlusExt index Reduction Method Pantelides failed! - OpenModelica

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

[I want to model a storage using phase change materials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySC9m.png). Basically, a hot heat transfer medium flows into one plate of the exchanger and a cold heat transfer medium flows in counterflow into another plate. The plate is located between 2 layers of encapsulated PCM. I would like to determine the outlet temperature of the hot and cold heat carriers for each instant. I made a spatial discretization (2D for the MCP part and 1D for the heat carriers).

When simulating my model, I get 9 error messages. Here are some examples of messages obtained:

```
[1] 14:20:03 Ecriture Notification
Skipped loading package SYNERGI (3,default) using MODELICAPATH C:/Program Files/OpenModelica/lib/omlibrary (uses-annotation may be wrong)
[3] 14:20:03 Traduction Erreur
Internal error DAEUtil.traverseDAEEquationsStmts not implemented correctly:   for x in 1:1 loop
    A := (ratio_a * PCM.ks_MCP + (1.0 - ratio_a) * Fin.k_ailettes) / 0.2;
    der(A) := 0.0;
    B := ratio_a * (PCM.kl_MCP - PCM.ks_MCP) / 0.2;
    der(B) := 0.0;
    A_prim := T_xy[x,y + 2,1] - 4.0 * T_xy[x,y + 1,1];
    der(A_prim) := -0.0;
    C_xy := (((-fl_xy[x,y + 2,1]) + 4.0 * fl_xy[x,y + 1,1]) / 0.2 * ((-T_xy[x,y + 2,1]) + 4.0 * T_xy[x,y + 1,1]) / 0.2 + ((-fl_xy[x + 2,y,1]) + 4.0 * fl_xy[x + 1,y,1]) / 0.2 * ((-T_xy[x + 2,y,1]) + 4.0 * T_xy[x + 1,y,1]) / 0.2) * ratio_a * (PCM.ks_MCP - PCM.kl_MCP) - (((-5.0 * T_xy[x,y + 1,1]) + 4.0 * T_xy[x,y + 2,1] - T_xy[x,y + 3,1]) / 0.01 + ((-5.0 * T_xy[x + 1,y,1]) + 4.0 * T_xy[x + 2,y,1] - T_xy[x + 3,y,1]) / 0.01) * (ratio_a * PCM.ks_MCP + (1.0 - ratio_a) * Fin.k_ailettes);
    der(C_xy) := 0.0;
    CC_xy := ratio_a * (PCM.kl_MCP - PCM.ks_MCP) * (((-5.0 * T_xy[x,y + 1,1]) + 4.0 * T_xy[x,y + 2,1] - T_xy[x,y + 3,1]) / 0.01 + ((-5.0 * T_xy[x + 1,y,1]) + 4.0 * T_xy[x + 2,y,1] - T_xy[x + 3,y,1]) / 0.01) + ratio_a * (PCM.kl_MCP - PCM.ks_MCP) * (((-3.0 * T_xy[x + 2,y,1]) + 12.0 * T_xy[x + 1,y,1]) / 0.04000000000000001 + ((-3.0 * T_xy[x,y + 2,1]) + 12.0 * T_xy[x,y + 1,1]) / 0.04000000000000001);
    der(CC_xy) := 0.0;
    D_xy := -(3.0 * ratio_a * (PCM.kl_MCP - PCM.ks_MCP) * (((-fl_xy[x,y + 2,1]) + 4.0 * fl_xy[x,y + 1,1]) / 0.04000000000000001 + ((-fl_xy[x + 2,y,1]) + 4.0 * fl_xy[x + 1,y,1]) / 0.04000000000000001) + 2.0 * (ratio_a * PCM.ks_MCP + (1.0 - ratio_a) * Fin.k_ailettes) * 200.0);
    der(D_xy) := -0.0;
    fl_xy[x,y,1] := (PCM.rho_MCP * PCM.h_latent * der(fl_xy[x,y,1]) + C_xy + D_xy * T_xy[x,y,1]) / (CC_xy + T_xy[x,y,1] * ratio_a * (PCM.kl_MCP - PCM.ks_MCP) * 849.9999999999999);
    T_xy[x,y,1] := (h_ext * T_ext + A * A_prim + B * A_prim * fl_xy[x,y,1]) / (h_ext - 3.0 * A - 3.0 * B * fl_xy[x,y,1]);
  end for;
[4] 17:05:49 Traduction Erreur
Internal error - IndexReduction.pantelidesIndexReductionMSS failed! Use -d=bltdump to get more information
[5] 14:20:03 Traduction Erreur
Internal error - IndexReduction.pantelidesIndexReductionMSS failed! Use -d=bltdump to get more information
[6] 14:20:04 Traduction Erreur
Internal error - IndexReduction.pantelidesIndexReduction1 failed! Use -d=bltdump to get more information
[7] 14:20:04 Traduction Erreur
Internal error - IndexReduction.pantelidesIndexReduction failed!
[8] 14:20:04 Traduction Erreur
Internal error Transformation Module PFPlusExt index Reduction Method Pantelides failed!
[9] 14:20:04 Ecriture Avertissement
Could not preserve the formatting of the model instead internal pretty-printing algorithm is used
```

This is my code:

```
model Octadecanol
      parameter Modelica.Units.SI.Temperature T_fusion=25;
      parameter Modelica.Units.SI.ThermalConductivity ks_MCP=0.301;
      parameter Modelica.Units.SI.ThermalConductivity kl_MCP=0.205;
      parameter Modelica.Units.SI.Density rho_MCP=850;
      parameter Modelica.Units.SI.SpecificHeatCapacity cp_MCP_s=1750;
      parameter Modelica.Units.SI.SpecificHeatCapacity cp_MCP_l=2150;
      type Heat=Real(unit="J.kg-1");
      parameter Heat h_latent = 226000;

    model Ailettes
      parameter Modelica.Units.SI.ThermalConductivity k_ailettes=20;
      parameter Modelica.Units.SI.Volume V_ailettes=0.2;
      parameter Modelica.Units.SI.Density rho_ailettes=1200;

    model Glycol
      parameter Modelica.Units.SI.ThermalConductivity k_c=0.6;
      parameter Modelica.Units.SI.DynamicViscosity mu_c=0.001139;
      parameter Modelica.Units.SI.Density rho_c=1000;
      parameter Modelica.Units.SI.SpecificHeatCapacity cp_c=4186;

    model Water
      parameter Modelica.Units.SI.ThermalConductivity k_f=0.6;
      parameter Modelica.Units.SI.DynamicViscosity mu_f=0.001139;
      parameter Modelica.Units.SI.Density rho_f=1000;
      parameter Modelica.Units.SI.SpecificHeatCapacity cp_f=4186;

model PCM
    Modelica.Units.SI.Temperature T_stock (start = T_init);
    Modelica.Units.SI.Temperature Ts_moy_c (start = T_init);
    Modelica.Units.SI.Temperature Ts_moy_f (start = T_init);
    Modelica.Units.SI.ThermalConductivity k_eff_MCP_ref;
    Modelica.Units.SI.ThermalConductivity k_MCP_ref;
    Modelica.Units.SI.SpecificHeatCapacity cp_MCP_ref;

    Water Cold;
    Glycol Hot;
    Octadecanol PCM;
    Ailettes Fin;

    parameter Modelica.Units.SI.Temperature T_ext = 15;
    parameter Modelica.Units.SI.MassFlowRate debit_sol = 60 * 150 / (3.6 * Hot.rho_c);
    parameter Modelica.Units.SI.Temperature T_out_PAC = 10;
    parameter Modelica.Units.SI.Temperature T_out_sol = 100;
    
    parameter Integer Nombre_MCP = 1;
    parameter Modelica.Units.SI.Length H_MCP = 0.4;
    parameter Modelica.Units.SI.Length P_MCP = 0.4;
    parameter Modelica.Units.SI.Length L_MCP = 0.4;
    parameter Modelica.Units.SI.Length L_tuyau = 0.05;
    parameter Modelica.Units.SI.Temperature T_init = 15;
    parameter Modelica.Units.SI.Mass M_MCP = 50;
    parameter Modelica.Units.SI.Volume V_MCP = M_MCP / PCM.rho_MCP;
    parameter Modelica.Units.SI.Length L_batt_tot = (L_MCP + 2) * Nombre_MCP + L_MCP;
    parameter Modelica.Units.SI.Length d_h_tuyau = 2 * S ^ 2 / (P_MCP + L_tuyau);
    parameter Modelica.Units.SI.Area S = P_MCP * L_tuyau;
    parameter Modelica.Units.SI.MassFlowRate debit_PAC = 2.5;
    parameter Modelica.Units.SI.MassFlowRate debit_f = debit_PAC / Nombre_MCP;
    parameter Modelica.Units.SI.MassFlowRate debit_c = debit_sol / Nombre_MCP;
    parameter Modelica.Units.SI.DimensionlessRatio ratio_a = V_MCP / (V_MCP + Fin.V_ailettes);
    parameter Modelica.Units.SI.CoefficientOfHeatTransfer h_ext = 500;
    parameter Modelica.Units.SI.CoefficientOfHeatTransfer h_f = 0.664 * debit_f ^ 0.5 * Cold.k_f ^ (2 / 3) * Cold.cp_f ^ (1 / 3) / (Cold.mu_f ^ (1 / 6) * d_h_tuyau);
    parameter Modelica.Units.SI.CoefficientOfHeatTransfer h_c = 0.664 * debit_c ^ 0.5 * Hot.k_c ^ (2 / 3) * Hot.cp_c ^ (1 / 3) / (Hot.mu_c ^ (1 / 6) * d_h_tuyau);
    parameter Modelica.Units.SI.CoefficientOfHeatTransfer h_cf = 1 / (1 / h_c + 1 / h_f);

    parameter Real Delta_x = 0.1;
    parameter Real Delta_y = 0.1;
    parameter Integer x_tot = integer(L_MCP / Delta_x);
    parameter Integer y_tot = integer(H_MCP / Delta_y);

    final constant Real pi = 2 * Modelica.Math.asin(1.0);

    Real[:, :] Tc_y (start = fill(T_init, y_tot, Nombre_MCP));
    Real[:, :] Tf_y (start = fill(T_init, y_tot, Nombre_MCP));
    Real[:, :, :] T_xy (start = fill(PCM.T_fusion, x_tot, y_tot, Nombre_MCP + 1));
    Real[:, :, :] fl_xy (start = fill(0, x_tot, y_tot, Nombre_MCP + 1));
    Real[:, :] racines (start = fill(0, 2, 2));
    Real Poly_1, Poly_2, Poly_3;

    Real A, A_prim, B, C_y_prim, C_xy, C_xy_trio, CC_y, CC_xy, CC_xy_trio, D_y_prim, D_xy, D_xy_trio, E, G, H, I, L, N;
    // Real K, J, H_prim, I_prim;
  algorithm
    k_MCP_ref := PCM.ks_MCP + fl_xy[1, 1, 1] * (PCM.kl_MCP - PCM.ks_MCP);
    k_eff_MCP_ref := ratio_a * k_MCP_ref + (1 - ratio_a) * Fin.k_ailettes;
    cp_MCP_ref := PCM.cp_MCP_s + fl_xy[1,1,1] * (PCM.cp_MCP_l - PCM.cp_MCP_s);

for y in 1:1 loop
      for x in 1:1 loop
        A := (ratio_a * PCM.ks_MCP + (1 - ratio_a) * Fin.k_ailettes) / (2 * Delta_y);
        B := ratio_a * (PCM.kl_MCP - PCM.ks_MCP) / (2 * Delta_y);
        A_prim := T_xy[x, y + 2, 1] - 4 * T_xy[x, y + 1, 1];
        C_xy := (((-fl_xy[x, y + 2, 1]) + 4 * fl_xy[x, y + 1, 1]) / (2 * Delta_y) * ((-T_xy[x, y + 2, 1]) + 4 * T_xy[x, y + 1, 1]) / (2 * Delta_y) + ((-fl_xy[x + 2, y, 1]) + 4 * fl_xy[x + 1, y, 1]) / (2 * Delta_x) * ((-T_xy[x + 2, y, 1]) + 4 * T_xy[x + 1, y, 1]) / (2 * Delta_x)) * ratio_a * (PCM.ks_MCP - PCM.kl_MCP) - (((-5 * T_xy[x, y + 1, 1]) + 4 * T_xy[x, y + 2, 1] - T_xy[x, y + 3, 1]) / Delta_y ^ 2 + ((-5 * T_xy[x + 1, y, 1]) + 4 * T_xy[x + 2, y, 1] - T_xy[x + 3, y, 1]) / Delta_x ^ 2) * (ratio_a * PCM.ks_MCP + (1 - ratio_a) * Fin.k_ailettes);
        CC_xy := ratio_a * (PCM.kl_MCP - PCM.ks_MCP) * (((-5 * T_xy[x, y + 1, 1]) + 4 * T_xy[x, y + 2, 1] - T_xy[x, y + 3, 1]) / Delta_y ^ 2 + ((-5 * T_xy[x + 1, y, 1]) + 4 * T_xy[x + 2, y, 1] - T_xy[x + 3, y, 1]) / Delta_x ^ 2) + ratio_a * (PCM.kl_MCP - PCM.ks_MCP) * (((-3 * T_xy[x + 2, y, 1]) + 12 * T_xy[x + 1, y, 1]) / (4 * Delta_x ^ 2) + ((-3 * T_xy[x, y + 2, 1]) + 12 * T_xy[x, y + 1, 1]) / (4 * Delta_y ^ 2));
        D_xy := -(3 * ratio_a * (PCM.kl_MCP - PCM.ks_MCP) * (((-fl_xy[x, y + 2, 1]) + 4 * fl_xy[x, y + 1, 1]) / (4 * Delta_y ^ 2) + ((-fl_xy[x + 2, y, 1]) + 4 * fl_xy[x + 1, y, 1]) / (4 * Delta_x ^ 2)) + 2 * (ratio_a * PCM.ks_MCP + (1 - ratio_a) * Fin.k_ailettes) * (1 / Delta_x ^ 2 + 1 / Delta_y ^ 2));
        fl_xy[x, y, 1] := (PCM.rho_MCP * PCM.h_latent * der(fl_xy[x, y, 1]) + C_xy + D_xy * T_xy[x, y, 1]) / (CC_xy + T_xy[x, y, 1] * ratio_a * (PCM.kl_MCP - PCM.ks_MCP) * (17 / (4 * Delta_y ^ 2) + 17 / (4 * Delta_x ^ 2)));
        T_xy[x, y, 1] := (h_ext * T_ext + A * A_prim + B * A_prim * fl_xy[x, y, 1]) / (h_ext - 3 * A - 3 * B * fl_xy[x, y, 1]);
      end for;

      for x in 2:x_tot - 1 loop
        C_y_prim := (((-fl_xy[x, y + 2, 1]) + 4 * fl_xy[x, y + 1, 1]) / (2 * Delta_y) * ((-T_xy[x, y + 2, 1]) + 4 * T_xy[x, y + 1, 1]) / (2 * Delta_y) + (fl_xy[x + 1, y, 1] - fl_xy[x - 1, y, 1]) / (2 * Delta_x) * (T_xy[x + 1, y, 1] - T_xy[x - 1, y, 1]) / (2 * Delta_x)) * ratio_a * (PCM.ks_MCP - PCM.kl_MCP) - (((-5 * T_xy[x, y + 1, 1]) + 4 * T_xy[x, y + 2, 1] - T_xy[x, y + 3, 1]) / Delta_y ^ 2 + (T_xy[x + 1, y, 1] + T_xy[x - 1, y, 1]) / Delta_x ^ 2) * (ratio_a * PCM.ks_MCP + (1 - ratio_a) * Fin.k_ailettes);
        CC_y := ratio_a * (PCM.kl_MCP - PCM.ks_MCP) * (((-5 * T_xy[x, y + 1, 1]) + 4 * T_xy[x, y + 2, 1] - T_xy[x, y + 3, 1]) / Delta_y ^ 2 + (T_xy[x + 1, y, 1] + T_xy[x - 1, y, 1]) / Delta_x ^ 2) + ratio_a * (PCM.kl_MCP - PCM.ks_MCP) * (3 * T_xy[x, y + 2, 1] - 12 * T_xy[x, y + 1, 1]) / (4 * Delta_y ^ 2);
        D_y_prim := -(3 * ratio_a * (PCM.kl_MCP - PCM.ks_MCP) * (fl_xy[x, y + 2, 1] - 4 * fl_xy[x, y + 1, 1]) / (4 * Delta_y ^ 2) + 2 * (ratio_a * PCM.ks_MCP + (1 - ratio_a) * Fin.k_ailettes) * (1 / Delta_y ^ 2 - 1 / Delta_x ^ 2));
        fl_xy[x, y, 1] := (PCM.rho_MCP * PCM.h_latent * der(fl_xy[x, y, 1]) + C_y_prim + D_y_prim * T_xy[x, y, 1]) / (CC_y + T_xy[x, y, 1] * ratio_a * (PCM.kl_MCP - PCM.ks_MCP) * (17 / (4 * Delta_y ^ 2) - 2 / Delta_x ^ 2));
        E := der(fl_xy[x, y, 1]) * (PCM.cp_MCP_s - PCM.cp_MCP_l);
        Poly_1 := E * ratio_a * (PCM.kl_MCP - PCM.ks_MCP) * (17 / (4 * Delta_y ^ 2) - 2 / Delta_x ^ 2);
        Poly_2 := E * CC_y - D_y_prim * der(T_xy[x, y, 1]) * (PCM.cp_MCP_l - PCM.cp_MCP_s) - E * PCM.T_fusion * ratio_a * (PCM.cp_MCP_l - PCM.cp_MCP_s) * (17 / (4 * Delta_y ^ 2) - 2 / Delta_x ^ 2) - PCM.cp_MCP_s * der(T_xy[x, y, 1]) * ratio_a * (PCM.kl_MCP - PCM.ks_MCP) * (17 / (4 * Delta_y ^ 2) - 2 / Delta_x ^ 2);
        Poly_3 := -(E * PCM.T_fusion * CC_y - PCM.cp_MCP_s * der(T_xy[x, y, 1]) * CC_y - C_y_prim * der(T_xy[x, y, 1]) * (PCM.cp_MCP_l - PCM.cp_MCP_s) - PCM.rho_MCP * PCM.h_latent * der(fl_xy[x, y, 1]) * der(T_xy[x, y, 1]) * (PCM.cp_MCP_l - PCM.cp_MCP_s));
        racines := Modelica.Math.Polynomials.roots({Poly_1, Poly_2, Poly_3});
        T_xy[x, y, 1] := racines[1, 1];
      end for;

      for x in x_tot:x_tot loop
        A := (ratio_a * PCM.ks_MCP + (1 - ratio_a) * Fin.k_ailettes) / (2 * Delta_y);
        B := ratio_a * (PCM.ks_MCP - PCM.kl_MCP) / (2 * Delta_y);
        G := T_xy[x, y + 2, 1] - 4 * T_xy[x, y + 1, 1];
        C_xy_trio := (((-fl_xy[x, y + 2, 1]) + 4 * fl_xy[x, y + 1, 1]) / (2 * Delta_y) * ((-T_xy[x, y + 2, 1]) + 4 * T_xy[x, y + 1, 1]) / (2 * Delta_y) + (fl_xy[x - 2, y, 1] - 4 * fl_xy[x - 1, y, 1]) / (2 * Delta_x) * (T_xy[x - 2, y, 1] - 4 * T_xy[x - 1, y, 1]) / (2 * Delta_x)) * ratio_a * (PCM.ks_MCP - PCM.kl_MCP) - (((-5 * T_xy[x, y + 1, 1]) + 4 * T_xy[x, y + 2, 1] - T_xy[x, y + 3, 1]) / Delta_y ^ 2 + ((-5 * T_xy[x - 1, y, 1]) + 4 * T_xy[x - 2, y, 1] - T_xy[x - 3, y, 1]) / Delta_x ^ 2) * (ratio_a * PCM.ks_MCP + (1 - ratio_a) * Fin.k_ailettes);
        CC_xy_trio := ratio_a * (PCM.kl_MCP - PCM.ks_MCP) * (((-5 * T_xy[x, y + 1, 1]) + 4 * T_xy[x, y + 2, 1] - T_xy[x, y + 3, 1]) / Delta_y ^ 2 + ((-5 * T_xy[x - 1, y, 1]) + 4 * T_xy[x - 2, y, 1] - T_xy[x - 3, y, 1]) / Delta_x ^ 2) + ratio_a * (PCM.kl_MCP - PCM.ks_MCP) * ((3 * T_xy[x - 2, y, 1] - 12 * T_xy[x - 1, y, 1]) / (4 * Delta_x ^ 2) + ((-3 * T_xy[x, y + 2, 1]) + 12 * T_xy[x, y + 1, 1]) / (4 * Delta_y ^ 2));
        D_xy_trio := -(3 * ratio_a * (PCM.kl_MCP - PCM.ks_MCP) * (((-fl_xy[x, y + 2, 1]) + 4 * fl_xy[x, y + 1, 1]) / (4 * Delta_y ^ 2) + (fl_xy[x - 2, y, 1] - 4 * fl_xy[x - 1, y, 1]) / (4 * Delta_x ^ 2)) + 2 * (ratio_a * PCM.ks_MCP + (1 - ratio_a) * Fin.k_ailettes) * (1 / Delta_x ^ 2 + 1 / Delta_y ^ 2));
        fl_xy[x, y, 1] := (PCM.rho_MCP * PCM.h_latent * der(fl_xy[x, y, 1]) + C_xy_trio + D_xy_trio * T_xy[x, y, 1]) / (CC_xy_trio + T_xy[x, y, 1] * ratio_a * (PCM.kl_MCP - PCM.ks_MCP) * (17 / (4 * Delta_y ^ 2) + 17 / (4 * Delta_x ^ 2)));
        T_xy[x, y, 1] := (Tc_y[y, 1] * h_c + A * G + B * G * fl_xy[x, y, 1]) / (h_c - 3 * A - 3 * B * fl_xy[x, y, 1]);
      end for;

      H := h_cf * Delta_y + h_c * Delta_y - 3 * debit_c * Hot.cp_c / (2 * Delta_y);
      I := (-Hot.rho_c * Delta_y * L_tuyau * Hot.cp_c * der(Tc_y[y, 1])) - debit_c * Hot.cp_c * (4 * Tc_y[y + 1, 1] - Tc_y[y + 2, 1]) / (2 * Delta_y);
      Tc_y[y, 1] := (I + h_cf * Tf_y[y, 1] + h_c * Delta_y * T_xy[x_tot, y, 1]) / H;
// J := h_f*Delta_y-h_cf*Delta_y+(3*debit_f*Cold.cp_f)/(2*Delta_y);
// K := Cold.rho_f*Delta_y*L_tuyau*Cold.cp_f*der(Tf_y[y,1]) + debit_f*Cold.cp_f*(4*Tf_y[y+1,1]-Tf_y[y+2,1])/(2*Delta_y);
// Tf_y[y,1] := (K+h_f*Delta_y*T_xy[1,y,2]-h_cf*Delta_y*Tc_y[y,1]) / J;
      Tf_y[y, 1] := T_out_PAC;

for k in 2:Nombre_MCP loop
        for x in 1:1 loop
          A := (ratio_a * PCM.ks_MCP + (1 - ratio_a) * Fin.k_ailettes) / (2 * Delta_y);
          B := ratio_a * (PCM.kl_MCP - PCM.ks_MCP) / (2 * Delta_y);
          L := (-T_xy[x, y + 2, k]) + 4 * T_xy[x, y + 1, k];
          C_xy := (((-fl_xy[x, y + 2, k]) + 4 * fl_xy[x, y + 1, k]) / (2 * Delta_y) * ((-T_xy[x, y + 2, k]) + 4 * T_xy[x, y + 1, k]) / (2 * Delta_y) + ((-fl_xy[x + 2, y, k]) + 4 * fl_xy[x + 1, y, k]) / (2 * Delta_x) * ((-T_xy[x + 2, y, k]) + 4 * T_xy[x + 1, y, k]) / (2 * Delta_x)) * ratio_a * (PCM.ks_MCP - PCM.kl_MCP) - (((-5 * T_xy[x, y + 1, k]) + 4 * T_xy[x, y + 2, k] - T_xy[x, y + 3, k]) / Delta_y ^ 2 + ((-5 * T_xy[x + 1, y, k]) + 4 * T_xy[x + 2, y, k] - T_xy[x + 3, y, k]) / Delta_x ^ 2) * (ratio_a * PCM.ks_MCP + (1 - ratio_a) * Fin.k_ailettes);
          CC_xy := ratio_a * (PCM.kl_MCP - PCM.ks_MCP) * (((-5 * T_xy[x, y + 1, k]) + 4 * T_xy[x, y + 2, k] - T_xy[x, y + 3, k]) / Delta_y ^ 2 + ((-5 * T_xy[x + 1, y, k]) + 4 * T_xy[x + 2, y, k] - T_xy[x + 3, y, k]) / Delta_x ^ 2) + ratio_a * (PCM.kl_MCP - PCM.ks_MCP) * (((-3 * T_xy[x + 2, y, k]) + 12 * T_xy[x + 1, y, k]) / (4 * Delta_x ^ 2) + ((-3 * T_xy[x, y + 2, k]) + 12 * T_xy[x, y + 1, k]) / (4 * Delta_y ^ 2));
          D_xy := -(3 * ratio_a * (PCM.kl_MCP - PCM.ks_MCP) * (((-fl_xy[x, y + 2, k]) + 4 * fl_xy[x, y + 1, k]) / (4 * Delta_y ^ 2) + ((-fl_xy[x + 2, y, k]) + 4 * fl_xy[x + 1, y, k]) / (4 * Delta_x ^ 2)) + 2 * (ratio_a * PCM.ks_MCP + (1 - ratio_a) * Fin.k_ailettes) * (1 / Delta_x ^ 2 + 1 / Delta_y ^ 2));
          fl_xy[x, y, k] := (PCM.rho_MCP * PCM.h_latent * der(fl_xy[x, y, k]) + C_xy + D_xy * T_xy[x, y, k]) / (CC_xy + T_xy[x, y, k] * ratio_a * (PCM.kl_MCP - PCM.ks_MCP) * (17 / (4 * Delta_y ^ 2) + 17 / (4 * Delta_x ^ 2)));
          T_xy[x, y, k] := (h_f * Tf_y[y, k] + A * L + B * L * fl_xy[x, y, k]) / (h_f + 3 * A + 3 * B * fl_xy[x, y, k]);
        end for;

        for x in 2:x_tot - 1 loop
          C_y_prim := (((-fl_xy[x, y + 2, k]) + 4 * fl_xy[x, y + 1, k]) / (2 * Delta_y) * ((-T_xy[x, y + 2, k]) + 4 * T_xy[x, y + 1, k]) / (2 * Delta_y) + (fl_xy[x + 1, y, k] - fl_xy[x - 1, y, k]) / (2 * Delta_x) * (T_xy[x + 1, y, k] - T_xy[x - 1, y, k]) / (2 * Delta_x)) * ratio_a * (PCM.ks_MCP - PCM.kl_MCP) - (((-5 * T_xy[x, y + 1, k]) + 4 * T_xy[x, y + 2, k] - T_xy[x, y + 3, k]) / Delta_y ^ 2 + (T_xy[x + 1, y, k] + T_xy[x - 1, y, k]) / Delta_x ^ 2) * (ratio_a * PCM.ks_MCP + (1 - ratio_a) * Fin.k_ailettes);
          CC_y := ratio_a * (PCM.kl_MCP - PCM.ks_MCP) * (((-5 * T_xy[x, y + 1, k]) + 4 * T_xy[x, y + 2, k] - T_xy[x, y + 3, k]) / Delta_y ^ 2 + (T_xy[x + 1, y, k] + T_xy[x - 1, y, k]) / Delta_x ^ 2) + ratio_a * (PCM.kl_MCP - PCM.ks_MCP) * (3 * T_xy[x, y + 2, k] - 12 * T_xy[x, y + 1, k]) / (4 * Delta_y ^ 2);
          D_y_prim := -(3 * ratio_a * (PCM.kl_MCP - PCM.ks_MCP) * (fl_xy[x, y + 2, k] - 4 * fl_xy[x, y + 1, k]) / (4 * Delta_y ^ 2) + 2 * (ratio_a * PCM.ks_MCP + (1 - ratio_a) * Fin.k_ailettes) * (1 / Delta_y ^ 2 - 1 / Delta_x ^ 2));
          fl_xy[x, y, k] := (PCM.rho_MCP * PCM.h_latent * der(fl_xy[x, y, k]) + C_y_prim + D_y_prim * T_xy[x, y, k]) / (CC_y + T_xy[x, y, k] * ratio_a * (PCM.kl_MCP - PCM.ks_MCP) * (17 / (4 * Delta_y ^ 2) - 2 / Delta_x ^ 2));
          E := der(fl_xy[x, y, k]) * (PCM.cp_MCP_s - PCM.cp_MCP_l);
          Poly_1 := E * ratio_a * (PCM.kl_MCP - PCM.ks_MCP) * (17 / (4 * Delta_y ^ 2) - 2 / Delta_x ^ 2);
          Poly_2 := E * CC_y - D_y_prim * der(T_xy[x, y, k]) * (PCM.cp_MCP_l - PCM.cp_MCP_s) - E * PCM.T_fusion * ratio_a * (PCM.cp_MCP_l - PCM.cp_MCP_s) * (17 / (4 * Delta_y ^ 2) - 2 / Delta_x ^ 2) - PCM.cp_MCP_s * der(T_xy[x, y, k]) * ratio_a * (PCM.kl_MCP - PCM.ks_MCP) * (17 / (4 * Delta_y ^ 2) - 2 / Delta_x ^ 2);
          Poly_3 := -(E * PCM.T_fusion * CC_y - PCM.cp_MCP_s * der(T_xy[x, y, k]) * CC_y - C_y_prim * der(T_xy[x, y, k]) * (PCM.cp_MCP_l - PCM.cp_MCP_s) - PCM.rho_MCP * PCM.h_latent * der(fl_xy[x, y, k]) * der(T_xy[x, y, k]) * (PCM.cp_MCP_l - PCM.cp_MCP_s));
          racines := Modelica.Math.Polynomials.roots({Poly_1, Poly_2, Poly_3});
          T_xy[x, y, k] := racines[1, 1];
        end for;

        for x in x_tot:x_tot loop
          A := (ratio_a * PCM.ks_MCP + (1 - ratio_a) * Fin.k_ailettes) / (2 * Delta_y);
          B := ratio_a * (PCM.kl_MCP - PCM.ks_MCP) / (2 * Delta_y);
          G := T_xy[x, y + 2, k] - 4 * T_xy[x, y + 1, k];
          C_xy_trio := (((-fl_xy[x, y + 2, k]) + 4 * fl_xy[x, y + 1, k]) / (2 * Delta_y) * ((-T_xy[x, y + 2, k]) + 4 * T_xy[x, y + 1, k]) / (2 * Delta_y) + (fl_xy[x - 2, y, k] - 4 * fl_xy[x - 1, y, k]) / (2 * Delta_x) * (T_xy[x - 2, y, k] - 4 * T_xy[x - 1, y, k]) / (2 * Delta_x)) * ratio_a * (PCM.ks_MCP - PCM.kl_MCP) - (((-5 * T_xy[x, y + 1, k]) + 4 * T_xy[x, y + 2, k] - T_xy[x, y + 3, k]) / Delta_y ^ 2 + ((-5 * T_xy[x - 1, y, k]) + 4 * T_xy[x - 2, y, k] - T_xy[x - 3, y, k]) / Delta_x ^ 2) * (ratio_a * PCM.ks_MCP + (1 - ratio_a) * Fin.k_ailettes);
          CC_xy_trio := ratio_a * (PCM.kl_MCP - PCM.ks_MCP) * (((-5 * T_xy[x, y + 1, k]) + 4 * T_xy[x, y + 2, k] - T_xy[x, y + 3, k]) / Delta_y ^ 2 + ((-5 * T_xy[x - 1, y, k]) + 4 * T_xy[x - 2, y, k] - T_xy[x - 3, y, k]) / Delta_x ^ 2) + ratio_a * (PCM.kl_MCP - PCM.ks_MCP) * ((3 * T_xy[x - 2, y, k] - 12 * T_xy[x - 1, y, k]) / (4 * Delta_x ^ 2) + ((-3 * T_xy[x, y + 2, k]) + 12 * T_xy[x, y + 1, k]) / (4 * Delta_y ^ 2));
          D_xy_trio := -(3 * ratio_a * (PCM.kl_MCP - PCM.ks_MCP) * (((-fl_xy[x, y + 2, k]) + 4 * fl_xy[x, y + 1, k]) / (4 * Delta_y ^ 2) + (fl_xy[x - 2, y, k] - 4 * fl_xy[x - 1, y, k]) / (4 * Delta_x ^ 2)) + 2 * (ratio_a * PCM.ks_MCP + (1 - ratio_a) * Fin.k_ailettes) * (1 / Delta_x ^ 2 + 1 / Delta_y ^ 2));
          fl_xy[x, y, k] := (PCM.rho_MCP * PCM.h_latent * der(fl_xy[x, y, k]) + C_xy_trio + D_xy_trio * T_xy[x, y, k]) / (CC_xy_trio + T_xy[x, y, k] * ratio_a * (PCM.kl_MCP - PCM.ks_MCP) * (17 / (4 * Delta_y ^ 2) + 17 / (4 * Delta_x ^ 2)));
          T_xy[x, y, k] := (Tc_y[y, k] * h_c + A * G + B * G * fl_xy[x, y, k]) / (h_c - 3 * A - 3 * B * fl_xy[x, y, k]);
        end for;

        H := h_cf * Delta_y + h_c * Delta_y - 3 * debit_c * Hot.cp_c / (2 * Delta_y);
        I := (-Hot.rho_c * Delta_y * L_tuyau * Hot.cp_c * der(Tc_y[y, k])) - debit_c * Hot.cp_c * (4 * Tc_y[y + 1, k] - Tc_y[y + 2, k]) / (2 * Delta_y);
        Tc_y[y, k] := (I + h_cf * Tf_y[y, k] + h_c * Delta_y * T_xy[x_tot, y, k]) / H;
// J := h_f*Delta_y-h_cf*Delta_y+(3*debit_f*Cold.cp_f)/(2*Delta_y);
// K := Cold.rho_f*Delta_y*L_tuyau*Cold.cp_f*der(Tf_y[y,k]) + debit_f*Cold.cp_f*(4*Tf_y[y+1,k]-Tf_y[y+2,k])/(2*Delta_y);
// Tf_y[y,k] := (K+h_f*Delta_y*T_xy[1,y,k+1]-h_cf*Delta_y*Tc_y[y,k]) / J;
        Tf_y[y, k] := T_out_PAC;
      end for;

      for x in 1:1 loop
        A := (ratio_a * PCM.ks_MCP + (1 - ratio_a) * Fin.k_ailettes) / (2 * Delta_y);
        B := ratio_a * (PCM.kl_MCP - PCM.ks_MCP) / (2 * Delta_y);
        L := (-T_xy[x, y + 2, Nombre_MCP + 1]) + 4 * T_xy[x, y + 1, Nombre_MCP + 1];
        C_xy := (((-fl_xy[x, y + 2, Nombre_MCP + 1]) + 4 * fl_xy[x, y + 1, Nombre_MCP + 1]) / (2 * Delta_y) * ((-T_xy[x, y + 2, Nombre_MCP + 1]) + 4 * T_xy[x, y + 1, Nombre_MCP + 1]) / (2 * Delta_y) + ((-fl_xy[x + 2, y, Nombre_MCP + 1]) + 4 * fl_xy[x + 1, y, Nombre_MCP + 1]) / (2 * Delta_x) * ((-T_xy[x + 2, y, Nombre_MCP + 1]) + 4 * T_xy[x + 1, y, Nombre_MCP + 1]) / (2 * Delta_x)) * ratio_a * (PCM.ks_MCP - PCM.kl_MCP) - (((-5 * T_xy[x, y + 1, Nombre_MCP + 1]) + 4 * T_xy[x, y + 2, Nombre_MCP + 1] - T_xy[x, y + 3, Nombre_MCP + 1]) / Delta_y ^ 2 + ((-5 * T_xy[x + 1, y, Nombre_MCP + 1]) + 4 * T_xy[x + 2, y, Nombre_MCP + 1] - T_xy[x + 3, y, Nombre_MCP + 1]) / Delta_x ^ 2) * (ratio_a * PCM.ks_MCP + (1 - ratio_a) * Fin.k_ailettes);
        CC_xy := ratio_a * (PCM.kl_MCP - PCM.ks_MCP) * (((-5 * T_xy[x, y + 1, Nombre_MCP + 1]) + 4 * T_xy[x, y + 2, Nombre_MCP + 1] - T_xy[x, y + 3, Nombre_MCP + 1]) / Delta_y ^ 2 + ((-5 * T_xy[x + 1, y, Nombre_MCP + 1]) + 4 * T_xy[x + 2, y, Nombre_MCP + 1] - T_xy[x + 3, y, Nombre_MCP + 1]) / Delta_x ^ 2) + ratio_a * (PCM.kl_MCP - PCM.ks_MCP) * (((-3 * T_xy[x + 2, y, Nombre_MCP + 1]) + 12 * T_xy[x + 1, y, Nombre_MCP + 1]) / (4 * Delta_x ^ 2) + ((-3 * T_xy[x, y + 2, Nombre_MCP + 1]) + 12 * T_xy[x, y + 1, Nombre_MCP + 1]) / (4 * Delta_y ^ 2));
        D_xy := -(3 * ratio_a * (PCM.kl_MCP - PCM.ks_MCP) * (((-fl_xy[x, y + 2, Nombre_MCP + 1]) + 4 * fl_xy[x, y + 1, Nombre_MCP + 1]) / (4 * Delta_y ^ 2) + ((-fl_xy[x + 2, y, Nombre_MCP + 1]) + 4 * fl_xy[x + 1, y, Nombre_MCP + 1]) / (4 * Delta_x ^ 2)) + 2 * (ratio_a * PCM.ks_MCP + (1 - ratio_a) * Fin.k_ailettes) * (1 / Delta_x ^ 2 + 1 / Delta_y ^ 2));
        fl_xy[x, y, Nombre_MCP + 1] := (PCM.rho_MCP * PCM.h_latent * der(fl_xy[x, y, Nombre_MCP + 1]) + C_xy + D_xy * T_xy[x, y, Nombre_MCP + 1]) / (CC_xy + T_xy[x, y, Nombre_MCP + 1] * ratio_a * (PCM.kl_MCP - PCM.ks_MCP) * (17 / (4 * Delta_y ^ 2) + 17 / (4 * Delta_x ^ 2)));
        T_xy[x, y, Nombre_MCP + 1] := (h_f * Tf_y[y, Nombre_MCP] + A * L + B * L * fl_xy[x, y, Nombre_MCP + 1]) / (h_f + 3 * A + 3 * B * fl_xy[x, y, Nombre_MCP + 1]);
      end for;

      for x in 2:x_tot - 1 loop
        C_y_prim := (((-fl_xy[x, y + 2, Nombre_MCP + 1]) + 4 * fl_xy[x, y + 1, Nombre_MCP + 1]) / (2 * Delta_y) * ((-T_xy[x, y + 2, Nombre_MCP + 1]) + 4 * T_xy[x, y + 1, Nombre_MCP + 1]) / (2 * Delta_y) + (fl_xy[x + 1, y, Nombre_MCP + 1] - fl_xy[x - 1, y, Nombre_MCP + 1]) / (2 * Delta_x) * (T_xy[x + 1, y, Nombre_MCP + 1] - T_xy[x - 1, y, Nombre_MCP + 1]) / (2 * Delta_x)) * ratio_a * (PCM.ks_MCP - PCM.kl_MCP) - (((-5 * T_xy[x, y + 1, Nombre_MCP + 1]) + 4 * T_xy[x, y + 2, Nombre_MCP + 1] - T_xy[x, y + 3, Nombre_MCP + 1]) / Delta_y ^ 2 + (T_xy[x + 1, y, Nombre_MCP + 1] + T_xy[x - 1, y, Nombre_MCP + 1]) / Delta_x ^ 2) * (ratio_a * PCM.ks_MCP + (1 - ratio_a) * Fin.k_ailettes);
        CC_y := ratio_a * (PCM.kl_MCP - PCM.ks_MCP) * (((-5 * T_xy[x, y + 1, Nombre_MCP + 1]) + 4 * T_xy[x, y + 2, Nombre_MCP + 1] - T_xy[x, y + 3, Nombre_MCP + 1]) / Delta_y ^ 2 + (T_xy[x + 1, y, Nombre_MCP + 1] + T_xy[x - 1, y, Nombre_MCP + 1]) / Delta_x ^ 2) + ratio_a * (PCM.kl_MCP - PCM.ks_MCP) * (3 * T_xy[x, y + 2, Nombre_MCP + 1] - 12 * T_xy[x, y + 1, Nombre_MCP + 1]) / (4 * Delta_y ^ 2);
        D_y_prim := -(3 * ratio_a * (PCM.kl_MCP - PCM.ks_MCP) * (fl_xy[x, y + 2, Nombre_MCP + 1] - 4 * fl_xy[x, y + 1, Nombre_MCP + 1]) / (4 * Delta_y ^ 2) + 2 * (ratio_a * PCM.ks_MCP + (1 - ratio_a) * Fin.k_ailettes) * (1 / Delta_y ^ 2 - 1 / Delta_x ^ 2));
        fl_xy[x, y, Nombre_MCP + 1] := (PCM.rho_MCP * PCM.h_latent * der(fl_xy[x, y, Nombre_MCP + 1]) + C_y_prim + D_y_prim * T_xy[x, y, Nombre_MCP + 1]) / (CC_y + T_xy[x, y, Nombre_MCP + 1] * ratio_a * (PCM.kl_MCP - PCM.ks_MCP) * (17 / (4 * Delta_y ^ 2) - 2 / Delta_x ^ 2));
        E := der(fl_xy[x, y, Nombre_MCP + 1]) * (PCM.cp_MCP_s - PCM.cp_MCP_l);
        Poly_1 := E * ratio_a * (PCM.kl_MCP - PCM.ks_MCP) * (17 / (4 * Delta_y ^ 2) - 2 / Delta_x ^ 2);
        Poly_2 := E * CC_y - D_y_prim * der(T_xy[x, y, Nombre_MCP + 1]) * (PCM.cp_MCP_l - PCM.cp_MCP_s) - E * PCM.T_fusion * ratio_a * (PCM.cp_MCP_l - PCM.cp_MCP_s) * (17 / (4 * Delta_y ^ 2) - 2 / Delta_x ^ 2) - PCM.cp_MCP_s * der(T_xy[x, y, Nombre_MCP + 1]) * ratio_a * (PCM.kl_MCP - PCM.ks_MCP) * (17 / (4 * Delta_y ^ 2) - 2 / Delta_x ^ 2);
        Poly_3 := -(E * PCM.T_fusion * CC_y - PCM.cp_MCP_s * der(T_xy[x, y, Nombre_MCP + 1]) * CC_y - C_y_prim * der(T_xy[x, y, Nombre_MCP + 1]) * (PCM.cp_MCP_l - PCM.cp_MCP_s) - PCM.rho_MCP * PCM.h_latent * der(fl_xy[x, y, Nombre_MCP + 1]) * der(T_xy[x, y, Nombre_MCP + 1]) * (PCM.cp_MCP_l - PCM.cp_MCP_s));
        racines := Modelica.Math.Polynomials.roots({Poly_1, Poly_2, Poly_3});
        T_xy[x, y, Nombre_MCP + 1] := racines[1, 1];
      end for;

      for x in x_tot:x_tot loop
        A := (ratio_a * PCM.ks_MCP + (1 - ratio_a) * Fin.k_ailettes) / (2 * Delta_y);
        B := ratio_a * (PCM.kl_MCP - PCM.ks_MCP) / (2 * Delta_y);
        N := (-T_xy[x, y + 2, Nombre_MCP + 1]) - 4 * T_xy[x, y + 1, Nombre_MCP + 1];
        C_xy_trio := (((-fl_xy[x, y + 2, Nombre_MCP + 1]) + 4 * fl_xy[x, y + 1, Nombre_MCP + 1]) / (2 * Delta_y) * ((-T_xy[x, y + 2, Nombre_MCP + 1]) + 4 * T_xy[x, y + 1, Nombre_MCP + 1]) / (2 * Delta_y) + (fl_xy[x - 2, y, Nombre_MCP + 1] - 4 * fl_xy[x - 1, y, Nombre_MCP + 1]) / (2 * Delta_x) * (T_xy[x - 2, y, Nombre_MCP + 1] - 4 * T_xy[x - 1, y, Nombre_MCP + 1]) / (2 * Delta_x)) * ratio_a * (PCM.ks_MCP - PCM.kl_MCP) - (((-5 * T_xy[x, y + 1, Nombre_MCP + 1]) + 4 * T_xy[x, y + 2, Nombre_MCP + 1] - T_xy[x, y + 3, Nombre_MCP + 1]) / Delta_y ^ 2 + ((-5 * T_xy[x - 1, y, Nombre_MCP + 1]) + 4 * T_xy[x - 2, y, Nombre_MCP + 1] - T_xy[x - 3, y, Nombre_MCP + 1]) / Delta_x ^ 2) * (ratio_a * PCM.ks_MCP + (1 - ratio_a) * Fin.k_ailettes);
        CC_xy_trio := ratio_a * (PCM.kl_MCP - PCM.ks_MCP) * (((-5 * T_xy[x, y + 1, Nombre_MCP + 1]) + 4 * T_xy[x, y + 2, Nombre_MCP + 1] - T_xy[x, y + 3, Nombre_MCP + 1]) / Delta_y ^ 2 + ((-5 * T_xy[x - 1, y, Nombre_MCP + 1]) + 4 * T_xy[x - 2, y, Nombre_MCP + 1] - T_xy[x - 3, y, Nombre_MCP + 1]) / Delta_x ^ 2) + ratio_a * (PCM.kl_MCP - PCM.ks_MCP) * ((3 * T_xy[x - 2, y, Nombre_MCP + 1] - 12 * T_xy[x - 1, y, Nombre_MCP + 1]) / (4 * Delta_x ^ 2) + ((-3 * T_xy[x, y + 2, Nombre_MCP + 1]) + 12 * T_xy[x, y + 1, Nombre_MCP + 1]) / (4 * Delta_y ^ 2));
        D_xy_trio := -(3 * ratio_a * (PCM.kl_MCP - PCM.ks_MCP) * (((-fl_xy[x, y + 2, Nombre_MCP + 1]) + 4 * fl_xy[x, y + 1, Nombre_MCP + 1]) / (4 * Delta_y ^ 2) + (fl_xy[x - 2, y, Nombre_MCP + 1] - 4 * fl_xy[x - 1, y, Nombre_MCP + 1]) / (4 * Delta_x ^ 2)) + 2 * (ratio_a * PCM.ks_MCP + (1 - ratio_a) * Fin.k_ailettes) * (1 / Delta_x ^ 2 + 1 / Delta_y ^ 2));
        fl_xy[x, y, Nombre_MCP + 1] := (PCM.rho_MCP * PCM.h_latent * der(fl_xy[x, y, Nombre_MCP + 1]) + C_xy_trio + D_xy_trio * T_xy[x, y, Nombre_MCP + 1]) / (CC_xy_trio + T_xy[x, y, Nombre_MCP + 1] * ratio_a * (PCM.kl_MCP - PCM.ks_MCP) * (17 / (4 * Delta_y ^ 2) + 17 / (4 * Delta_x ^ 2)));
        T_xy[x, y, Nombre_MCP + 1] := (h_ext * T_ext + A * N + B * N * fl_xy[x, y, Nombre_MCP + 1]) / (h_ext + A + B * fl_xy[x, y, Nombre_MCP + 1]);
      end for;
    end for;

    Ts_moy_c := sum(Tc_y[1, :]) / Nombre_MCP;
    Ts_moy_f := sum(Tf_y[y_tot, :]) / Nombre_MCP;
    T_stock := Ts_moy_c;
end PCM;
```

Answer (score 1):

The code has the following problems:

1. For each of the medium models, the syntax should end with `end Octadecanol;`, `end Ailettes;` etc.
2. The model `Batterie_PCM` has 98 equations and 137 unknowns. For instance the variables `N_scnd`, `K_prim` etc. are not part of the equations.

Comment: The code is too long and cannot be fully integrated into the description.

Comment: I modified the code into the description